# Question about dafny to prove the Lemma in seq<int>

Tags: dafny

I just start learning with dafny. Now I have predicate:

```
predicate allEqual(s:seq<int>)
//{forall i,j::0<=i<|s| && 0<=j<|s| ==> s[i]==s[j] }
//{forall i,j::0<=i<=j<|s| ==> s[i]==s[j] }
//{forall i::0<i<|s| ==> s[i-1]==s[i]} 
{forall i::0<=i<|s|-1 ==> s[i]==s[i+1]}
```

and then I need to prove the Lemma :

```
lemma equivalenceContiguous(s:seq<int>)
ensures (allEqual(s) <==> forall i::0<=i<|s|-1 ==> s[i]==s[i+1])
```

how can I do to prove this? As I know I need to write "assert" or something?

Comment: Why is this tagged as c?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This proof is especially easy, since you're trying to prove that `allEqual` is what it is defined to be. Just add an empty body to the lemma:

```
lemma equivalenceContiguous(s: seq<int>)
  ensures allEqual(s) <==> forall i :: 0 <= i < |s| - 1 ==> s[i] == s[i+1]
{
}
```

Comment: I didn't thought that coming .. so all I need to do just add an empty body? But an empty body didn't mean anything... do you mean Dafny has the power of automatic proof some Lemma, and then he can understant this Lemma by himself?

Comment: To declare a lemma, you write something like `lemma Name(params: Types) ensures <Condition-to-prove>`. To give a proof, you follow that declaration with a block of code, just like you do for a `method`. In this case, the empty body is enough, because the proof is trivial.